# Is there a javascript equivalent of .= for self concatenating?

Tags: javascript

Rather than doing

```
my_var = my_var+'extra string';
```

is there a shorthand method like .= in php?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Use `+=`

```
var s = 'begin';
s += 'ning';
```

Comment: ha - should have guessed that!

Answer (score 5):

**Performance Tip** (*note* — this advice is valid for IE6, but it's no longer worth worrying about in 2014)

If you're writing some Javascript code to build up a long string (say, a fairly big block of HTML, or a long parameter list for an ajax request), then **don't get in the habit of doing this:**

```
var longString = "";
for (var i = 0; i < someBigNumber; ++i) {
  if (i > 0) longString += "<br>" + whatever;
  longString += someMoreStuff();
}
```

As the `longString` gets longer and longer, Internet Explorer will puff harder and harder on each iteration of the loop. Even when `someBigNumber` isn't really that big, the performance of that loop can be really terrible.

Luckily, there's an easy alternative: **use an array:**

```
var accumulator = [];
for (var i = 0; i < someBigNumber; ++i) {
  accumulator.push(someMoreStuff());
}
var longString = accumulator.join("<br>" + whatever);
```

**Way, way faster** in Internet Explorer than repeated string appends.

Comment: Better yet, Pointy, you big dummy, do stuff like that with a framework! Frameworks are generally very well optimized, and will generally do most everything in a well-tested, efficient, safe way.

Comment: Good answer, was about to write that.

Answer (score 2):

```
+=
```

Example:

```
my_var += "extra string";
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes: `my_var += 'extra string';`